# How to count $n$th percentile from normally distributed random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have normally distributed random variable $X\sim \mathcal N(100,225)$. How to count $n$th percentile?

In my case I need lower quartile - $x(0.25)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then
$$
\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
follows a standard normal distribution. If $F_X$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $\Phi$ is that of a standard normal distribution, then
$$
F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right).
$$
Let us find the $p$th quantile/percentile of $X$, where $p\in (0,1)$, in terms of the $p$th quantile/percentile of a standard normal distribution. Let $y$ denote the $p$th quantile of a standard normal distribution, i.e.
$$
\Phi(y_p)=p.
$$
If we let $x_p=\sigma y_p+\mu$ then
$$
F_X(x_p)=\Phi\left(\frac{x_p-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\Phi(y_p)=p,
$$
i.e. $x_p$ is the $p$th percent of $X$.

So all you need to know is the $p$th quantile of the standard normal distribution which can be found in tables, and then you can find $p$th quantiles for every normal distribution.

---

Note that some tables only index probabilities $p\geq 0.5$, because the rest can be deduced from these quantiles by symmetry. Recall that $1-\Phi(x)=\Phi(-x)$ for all $x$. If $q<0.5$ and $p=1-q$, then $p\geq 0.5$ and we can look up the $p$th quantile $x_p$. By symmetry:
$$
q=1-p=1-\Phi(x_p)=\Phi(-x_p)
$$
and so $x_q=-x_p$, i.e. the $q$th quantile is minus the $p$th quantile.

Comment: Thanks for your exhausting answer. According to your last sentence - what kind of tables do you mean? I have Z-table with probabilities for particular z-score in normal distribution. Do you mean it?

Comment: For example [this table](http://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/nchrp/cd-22/manual/v2appendixc.pdf). If you want the $99.4\%$ quantile, you find $0.994$ in the table, and read the corresponding $z$-value (in this case $z=0.251$). For $p$-values lower than $50\%$, please see my updated answer if your table doesn't include those.

Comment: I'll try to summarize your help if I understood you correctly. I have normally distributed random variable X~N(100,225) and I'm looking for Q1. I use z-table and find particular z-value for 0.25 => z = -0.67. Next I can use z-score equation z=(x-mean)/stdev. I know z-score, mean and stdev. So I can compute particular x value. In my case (Q1) -0.67=(x-100)/15 => x = 89.95. So I can say value on Q1 in my population is 89.95. Am I correct?

Comment: @user1315357: Yes, exactly.