# For a normally distributed random variable, find a value from given tail probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

#### Problem

Let $ X \sim N(65,20) $.
Find correct to $3$ Decimal Place the value of $x$ such that $Pr(X>x) = 0.43$.

#### Progress

I've gotten to $\frac {x-65}{2(5)^{1/2}} =0.1764$ and hence $x = 67.789$?
I'm not 100% sure where I've gone wrong with my working out?

Comment: Down-voted because the OP didn't indicate any interaction with their question.

Comment: @StefanHansen i've gotten to $\frac {x-65}{2(5)^{1/2}} =0.1764$ and hence $x = 67.789$ ??

Comment: Note that $P(X>x)=0.43$ if and only $P(X\leq x)=0.57$. So you need to find the $57\%$ quantile/percentile of an $\mathcal{N}(65,20)$ distribution. See e.g. [this explanation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294486/how-to-count-nth-percentile-from-normally-distributed-random-variable/294497#294497).

Comment: im not 100% sure where i've gone wrong with my working out?

Comment: The equation $$\frac{x-65}{\sqrt{20}}=0.1764$$ is correct (I don't know why you have written $\sqrt{20}$ as $2\cdot 5^{1/2}$ though). But this yields $x=0.1765\cdot \sqrt{20}+65$ which is $65.789$ and not $67.789$.

Comment: ohhh sorry musta been a typo, thankyou i understand it now. And that other explanation is AMAZING :)

Comment: @StefanHansen maybe you can post that as answer, so OP can accept?

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment as an answer. The equation
$$
\frac{x-65}{\sqrt{20}}=0.1764
$$
you proposed is correct. However, the solution to this is 
$$
0.1764\cdot \sqrt{20}+65\approx 65.789
$$ and *not* $67.789$.